# Show that the sequence $\Omega^0\Bbb{R}^2\ \longrightarrow\ \Omega^1\Bbb{R}^2\ \longrightarrow\ \Omega^2\Bbb{R}^2$ is exact.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, partial-derivative, exact-sequence

I have been posed the following question, which I am unable to answer:

> Let $a_1,a_2\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\Bbb{R}^2,\Bbb{R})$ be infinitely differentiable functions such that $\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_2}=\frac{\partial a_2}{\partial x_1}$, and define
>   $$f(x,y):=x_1\cdot\int_0^1a_1(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt+x_2\cdot\int_0^1a_2(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt.$$
>   Show that $\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=a_i$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$.

Unfortunately I lack even the most basic knowledge of calculus. Here's my attempt at a solution:

First by linearity of differentiation and second by the product rule and then cleaning up we find
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x_1,x_2)
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\left(x_1\cdot\int_0^1a_1(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\left(x_2\cdot\int_0^1a_2(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt\right)\\
&=x_1\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\left(\int_0^1a_1(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt\right)+\int_0^1a_1(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt\cdot\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_1}\\
&\hspace{10pt}+x_2\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\left(\int_0^1a_2(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt\right)+\int_0^1a_2(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt\cdot\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x_1}\\
&=\int_0^1a_1(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt+x_1\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\int_0^1a_1(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt+x_2\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\int_0^1a_2(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt.
\end{align*}
Now changing the order of integration and differentiation, which is allowed for whatever reason, and subsequently applying the chain rule and substituting $\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_2}=\frac{\partial a_2}{\partial x_1}$ we find that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x_1,x_2)
&=\int_0^1a_1(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt+x_1\cdot\int_0^1\frac{\partial a_1(tx_1,tx_2)}{\partial x_1}\ dt+x_2\cdot\int_0^1\frac{\partial a_2(tx_1,tx_2)}{\partial x_1}\ dt\\
&=\int_0^1a_1(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt+x_1\cdot\int_0^1\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_1}(tx_1,tx_2)\cdot t\ dt+x_2\cdot\int_0^1\frac{\partial a_2}{\partial x_1}(tx_1,tx_2)\cdot t\ dt\\
&=\int_0^1a_1(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt+x_1\cdot\int_0^1\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_1}(tx_1,tx_2)\cdot t\ dt+x_2\cdot\int_0^1\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_2}(tx_1,tx_2)\cdot t\ dt.
\end{align*}
These integrals look good for integration by parts with respect to $t$ and $\tfrac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_1}(tx_1,tx_2)$, which yields
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x_1,x_2)
&=\int_0^1a_1(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt+x_1\cdot\left(\left[t\cdot\int\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_1}(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt\right]_0^1-\int_0^1\int\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_1}(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt\ dt\right)\\
&\hspace{10pt}+x_2\cdot\left(\left[t\cdot\int\frac{\partial a_2}{\partial x_1}(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt\right]_0^1-\int_0^1\int\frac{\partial a_2}{\partial x_1}(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt\ dt\right).\\
\end{align*}
This is where my bright ideas end; I've juggled the terms around a bit but I see no way of evaluating any of these expressions. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} (x_1,x_2) =\int_0^1a_1(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt+x_1\cdot\int_0^1\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_1}(tx_1,tx_2)\cdot t\ dt+x_2\cdot\int_0^1\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_2}(tx_1,tx_2)\cdot t\ dt,$$

it is good. But then you took the wrong turn. The trick is that the sum of the integrands is a derivative with respect to $t$. Write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} (x_1,x_2) &= \int_0^1a_1(tx_1,tx_2)\,dt + \int_0^1 t\cdot\left( \frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_1}(tx_1,tx_2)\cdot x_1 + \frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_2}(tx_1,tx_2)\cdot x_2\right)\,dt\\
&= \int_0^1a_1(tx_1,tx_2)\ dt + \int_0^1 t\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial t}a_1(tx_1,tx_2)\,dt\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(t\cdot a_1(tx_1,tx_2)\right)\,dt\\
&= 1\cdot a_1(1\cdot x_1,1\cdot x_2) - 0 \cdot a_1(0,0)\\
&=a_1(x_1,x_2).
\end{align}$$

Comment: What a clever way to rewrite things, thank you very much!